# How can I make gdal2tiles tile layer smaller in size?

Tags: qgis, gdal2tiles

I am making tile layers that expand a large portion of North America using gdal2tiles. The output of 1 tile layer can be around 20GB or more. Is there a way to reduce the size of the tiles?

Comment: It is a python script and not very heavy to read. Source code is at https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal2tiles.py. I suppose that changing tileformat into jpeg would save space with aerial images. Tiles would not be transparent then.